# Does making a application webview load website not for me legal?

Tags: android, policy

How i can know if clone a website (not for me) into android webview application is legal if the website doesn't have in the bottom copyright ....

Comment: If by cloning you mean downloading then it is legal for any website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question regarding content licensing, not programming. Stack Overflow is not a law office. Contact your attorney with questions regarding whether or not something is "legal".

Comment: no I mean to load the web in webview inside the application

Comment: Why are you talking about cloning when you only want to display a website? You are of course allowed to use any browser you want. Including your own.

Comment: ok thank you i think display the website in webview mean cloning  :]